# Java Progress Bar Help

Tags: java, progress-bar, fileoutputstream

I need to implement a progress bar for the following task delay

```
FileOutputStream Fos= new FileOutputStream(FilePath);
byte buffer[]=Services.downloadFile(FilePath);
Fos.write(buffer);
```

Now, how can i know how much the file has been downloaded to update the progress bar

Comment: Where does the `Services` class come from?

Comment: I am using RMI and the Services is a proxy , this code is as if on a client, i'm requesting a file from a server using RMI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not easy since `Services.downloadFile()` doesn't give you the file in chunks. If you had a loop, it would be simple.

If you can change the API, I suggest to change it in this way:

```
Services.downloadFile(File, OutputStream);
```

and let `downloadFile()` write the file into the stream. Now you can wrap the stream and count  the bytes written by overloading the various versions of `write()`.

**[EDIT]** I saw that `Services` is an RMI proxy. In this case, you can't use the approach above. Instead it gets more complex:

You need a pool of downloads on your server (think "Map"). The pool allows you to request another block of data for each download.

So on your server, you need:

1. Create an object that handles the download and which has a `byte[] read()` method.
2. Put the objects into a map with a key. Send the key to the client somehow.
3. For each object, create a thread that actually downloads the data and adds the data to a buffer. The `read()` method returns the content of the buffer and clears it.

On the client:

1. You need to call a method on the server to create a new download object and start the download thread.
2. Now you need a loop that calls `read()` on the download object on the server. The API is something like `read(key)`, the server looks up the key in the map and then calls `read()` on the download object.
3. Show the progress as you write the result of the read calls to the file